# Performance of assigning multiple return values from function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, assign

I'm wondering if there's a way to assign the outputs of a function to variables, while only having to run the function once. For example, say I have a function like this:

```
def my_func(x):
    return x+1, x**2, x**3
```

And then I want to store each output as a variable, so normally I would code this afterwards:

```
var1 = my_func(2)[0]
var2 = my_func(2)[1]
var3 = my_func(2)[2]
```

But from my understanding, each line above requires the function to run again. If I have a longer function, it would be more convenient to assign them all at the same time, only running the function once. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

assign the function's return value (which is a `tuple`) to a variable, and access its elements:

```
var = my_func(2)
var1 = var[0]
var2 = var[1]
var3 = var[2]
```

or use unpacking:

```
var1, var2, var3 = my_func(2)
```

Re: Which method runs faster in most cases?

Let's compare the disassemble (I hilighted with `>` the differences):

`dis.dis('t=my_func(2);d=t[0]+t[1]+t[2]')`

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_func)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
           >  6 STORE_NAME               1 (t)
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (t)
           > 10 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
           > 12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             14 LOAD_NAME                1 (t)
           > 16 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           > 18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 BINARY_ADD
             22 LOAD_NAME                1 (t)
           > 24 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
           > 26 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 BINARY_ADD
             30 STORE_NAME               2 (d)
             32 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

`dis.dis('a,b,c=my_func(2);d=a+b+c')`

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_func)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
          >   6 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
          >   8 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
          >  10 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
          >  12 STORE_NAME               3 (c)
             14 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
             16 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
             18 BINARY_ADD
             20 LOAD_NAME                3 (c)
             22 BINARY_ADD
             24 STORE_NAME               4 (d)
             26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, the first approach takes two more instructions each time a variable is used (LOAD_CONST, BINARY_SUBSCR), while the second approach takes one more instruction when the variable is created.

The difference is practically meaningless.

Comment: Which method runs faster in most cases?

Comment: @WynneT I would guess the latter, but probably by a meaningless amount.

Comment: @WynneT: see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this via sequence unpacking:

```
def my_func(x):
    return x+1, x**2, x**3

var1, var2, var3 = my_func(2)
```

This feature is described in the docs: [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)